# else condition is getting true before if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Here is my javascript code. Initially, the else coding is being true before if the condition becomes true.

```
for(m=0;m<object[l].get("name").length;m++){
  if(object[l].get("name")[m]==userName){
    valid(userName);
  } else {
    notValid(userName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the userName value from, please include all relevant code

Comment: plz list the complete code. also use === wherever possible

Comment: are you trying to traverse an string? if so, maybe you should use `charAt` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)

Comment: There seems to be a logic error in your code, are you trying to check username against a list? If so, you shouldn't use `else` like this. You can only call `notValid` after you've iterated through all items.

Comment: Why mot save `object[l].get("name")` in a variable and access its properties directly

Comment: but how can I over come the challenge that if match found it will execute first?

Answer (score 0):

If `userName` is not equal with `object[l].get("name")[m]`, then else part will execute. If first object name matches with `userName`(means `object[l].get("name")[0]` matched with `userName`) then if block will execute first

Comment: but how can I overcome the challenge that if match found it will execute first?

Comment: You have to add one more condition inside if condition or use && to add condition, you have to check if m!=0, then if block will execute